# Linear regression on non numeric variables in R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I am trying to build a linear regression model for my data which has following variables.

```
[1] "Productcode"   "Category"    "Month"   "Mode.of.operations" "sales"   "profit.margin"     
 [7] "Name"         "Packaging.content"  "Specifications"     "Unit       "Origin"
```

Now as some of my variables are non numeric e.g `Origin` has values which are names of cities and countries, `Mode of operation` has values (joint venture, reseller, distributor).  In non numeric variable i dont know how to represent it in my linear regression model. One way I can think is to assign numeric values to these variables e.g `(Joint venture =1 , Reseller = 2 and Distribution =3)` but then it won't be right because it implies Distribution is better or 3 times higher than Joint venture.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem in R.

Comment: You treat them as factors. If you leave them as text labels R should convert them to factors when you read them in.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b (above) and Heroka (below). No need to worry as R will create dummy variables based on  the values (names) of your "Origin" column/variable. One thing you might need to take into account is the number of different values you have for "Origin". If you have many cities (eg. 200 cities in a dataset with 1000 rows) you might need to find a way to group/cluster those cities. Or if you have some cities represented by 1-2 rows in your dataset.

Comment: You might benefit from reading chapter 4 in 'An introduction to R' which ships with your copy of R.

Comment: If you end up converting your variable into 0, 1, or 2 (as suggested below), you should factorize them. You can use "as.factor()" function. But the best approach would be to leave them as characters.

Answer (score 1):

[I am assuming this is an issue with one of your independent variables. If it's in your dependent variable, linear regression is not the way to go]

You are right that assigning numeric variables is the wrong way to go. In linear regression with non-numeric (or categorical) independent variables, you want a coefficient for each category (except a default one). You need the variable to be a factor. You can either let R do this for you, by just adding the variable as-is to the model, or convert it to a factor yourself. That way, you can set which mode of operation is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the categorical variables to numeric based on the type

Categorical variables - Create column for each unique & create binary flag for them

Ordinal variables (categories with logical order e.g., high low medium) can be converted to values 1,2,3 etc

Language - You can use Word2Vec or Document Term matrix

Cities - You can create actual distance from respect to one city

So all of them will be numeric & you can use Linear regression

Hope this helps.